# Using if statements with std_msgs::String::ConstPtr

Tags: ros, std-msgs, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that is getting action calls from another node. Once it gets the action, I want to call a specific function but the if statement doesn't ever return true.

How can I get an if statement to work with a std_msgs string?

```
void chattersCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: %s", msg->data.c_str());
  if ((msg->data.c_str()) == "Listen") {sendStopAction();}
}
```

The terminal shows

```
[ INFO] [1381550860.740367371]: I heard: Listen
```

But the If statement does not return true. There is another print statement in the sendStopAction() function

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90041/using-if-statements-with-std_msgs::string::constptr/) by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess your code example should be:

```
if (msg->data.c_str() == "Listen") ...
```

In C++ you can not just compare two `char*`. You neither have to use `strcmp()` or use the comparison operator of std::string:

```
if (msg->data == "Listen") ...
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-10-11**:
Thank you. Yes, my code was msg->data.c_str(). I got confused and tried dropping the c_ just to see if it magically changed anything. Thanks again :)